# Restricting admin model entry

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a such model named Foo:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    entry = models.DateField()
```

I have 2 types of users who can login to the admin panel, regular and superusers. I want to disallow the edition/deletion of Foo  entries that are older than 2 days (by using the entry date field) but superusers may edit without any restriction.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override ModelAdmin's [queryset and has_change_permission](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/admin/#how-do-i-limit-admin-access-so-that-objects-can-only-be-edited-by-the-users-who-created-them) :

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin

class FooAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj):
        return obj is None or self.queryset(request).filter(pk=obj.pk).count() > 0

    def queryset(self, request):
        query = super(FooAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return query
        else:
            from datetime import datetime, timedelta 

            return query.filter(entry__gt=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=2))

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

has_change_permission is used by the change view, and queryset by the list view. I reuse the queryset inside the overridden has_change_permission to stay DRY ( so you can add additional filters in queryset without caring to add this logic in the change permission check ), but it's worth mentioning that it costs an additional query.

Comment: the method was renamed to `get_queryset` in django 1.6+